How to get only the list of TTS-capable voices in Swift?
I am fetching tts list as below
However, there are voices in the imported list that cannot be output.
When importing a list, is there a way to import only the TTS list that can output audio?
func getList() -> Array<CustomTtsData>
{
    var arr = Array<CustomTtsData>()
    
    for voice in AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices() {
        arr.append(CustomTtsData(voice.name, voice.language))
    }
    
    return arr
}


There are voices that cannot output audio? Can you give an example of such a voice?

@Sweeper - It seems to vary depending on the device, but on my phone, the Korean word 'yuna high quality' does not produce sound.
